# EditText style background specified in theme doesn't apply to EditTex?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-theme

[image]

I am creating an EditText like image. (Actually, I made it.)

Created `drawable xml` and set EditText as background.

However, to manage this more easily, I created a style in the `theme` and assigned it to the `style` property in `EditText`, but it is not applied.

What's the reason?

(Or if there is a better way to create these EditTexts please let me know)

--

**drawable**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/gray_400"/>
</shape>
```

**theme.xml**

```
<!--  memo EditText style  -->
<style name="MemoEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="background">@drawable/edittext_memo</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/gray_400</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/gray_400</item>
</style>
```

**in xml**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    style="@style/MemoEditTextStyle"
    android:hint="@string/hint_memo"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

**result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background is not applied to EditText because in the style you define a property `<item name="background">`  instead of `<item name="android:background">`.

The same result can be also achieved using `Widget.MaterialComponents` without the need of the drawable xml shape like in the below example:

**Define a custom TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox Style:**

```
<style name="Custom.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxBackgroundMode">outline</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">#c2c0ba</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">#c2c0ba</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeErrorColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">5dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">5dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">5dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">5dp</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="boxCollapsedPaddingTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="hintEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="errorIconDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="errorTextColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#B3B3B3</item>
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/Custom.ThemeOverlay.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom.ThemeOverlay.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Custom.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

**Usage:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Custom.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="MEMO"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image: textinputlayout]

Comment: Thank you. I'll just ask you two questions.

`1.` When is `@style` used in `parent="@style/..."`?

`2.` In the `IDE`, `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.` Or `@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.` After writing, `TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox` does not auto-complete, but no error occurs. For what reason?

Comment: @ybybyb parent="@style/..." is used when you want to inherit styles from a library or your own project. It’s optional so you can remove it if you want. The main purpose of this is to be distinguished from parent="@android:style/".
As for the second question its an IDE related issue but normally it should auto-complete.